# Filter nested elements in MongoDB using MongoTemplate Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I'm trying to filter array of fields whose title matches with given input array of titles and display the complete document excluding unmatched fields.I'm having below document. Actually, I want to achieve this using MongoTemplate but first I'm trying to get it via mongo query. Below is my document:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "pageName": "Content_2",
    "domain": "bingo.com",
    "locale": "en-us",
    "contents": [
        {
            "contentName": "Template_2",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "fieldType": "Plain Text",
                    "id": "companyName456",
                    "title": "Company Name",
                    "alternateText": "Company Name",
                    "value": "Microsoft",
                    "placeholder": "Enter your Company name"
                },
                {
                    "fieldType": "Plain Text",
                    "id": "designation789",
                    "title": "Designation",
                    "alternateText": "Designation",
                    "value": "Software Engineer",
                    "placeholder": "Enter your designation name"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried below query but it is returning empty result:

```
db.contents.aggregate(
  [
    { $match: { locale: "en-us" } },
    {
      $redact: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $in: [ "$title", ["Designation"] ] },
          then: "$$DESCEND",
          else: "$$PRUNE"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

I'm expecting below result:

```
{
    "pageName": "Home",
    "link": "hello.com",
    "locale": "en-us",
    "contents": [
        {
            "contentName": "Template_2",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "fieldType": "Plain Text",
                    "id": "designation789",
                    "title": "Designation",
                    "alternateText": "Designation",
                    "value": "Software Engineer",
                    "placeholder": "Enter your designation name"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please guide. I'm quite new to MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
db.contents.aggregate([
# Match that local
     {$match: { locale: "en-us" } },
# Unwind by contents and contents.fields
     {$unwind: "$contents"},
     {$unwind: "$contents.fields"},
# Match them
     {$match: { "contents.fields.title": "Designation" } },
# group back by _id of the document
     {$group: {
         "_id": "$_id",
         "contents": { "$push": "$contents" }
     }}
 ])
```

If you need all other fields group also by them like

```
db.contents.aggregate([
     {$match: { locale: "en-us" } },
     {$unwind: "$contents"},
     {$unwind: "$contents.fields"},
     {$match: { "contents.fields.title": "Designation" } },
     {$group: {
         "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "version": "$version",
            "pageName": "$pageName",
            "domain": "$domain",
            "locale": "$locale",

        },
         "contents": { "$push": "$contents" }
     }},
     {$project: {"version": "$_id.version", 
                 "_id": "$_id._id",
                 "pageName": "$_id.pageName",
                 "locale": "$_id.locale",
                 "domain": "$_id.domain",
                 "contents": "$contents",}}
 ])
```

Comment: thanks. It helped me. Inside $project, is there shorter way to project all outer fields? I had already tried this approach but I'm looking for a shorter solution.

Comment: as far as i know not, but I'm also new to mongo

Comment: I was able  to achieve my result using below query:
`db.contents.aggregate([
     {$match: { pageName: "Content_2"}},
     {$unwind: "$contents"},
     {$unwind: "$contents.fields"},
     {$match: { "contents.fields.title": {$in: ["Company Name"]}}},
     {$group: {
         "_id": "$_id",
         "contents": { "$push": "$contents" },
   "root":{$first:"$$ROOT"}
     }},
  {$replaceRoot:{newRoot:{$mergeObjects:["$root",{contents:'$contents'}]}}}
 ]);`